# angularjs: Downloaded file name is "Unknown" using Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

Downloaded the file in Safari the file name is "Unknown"
Here is my download code
function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {

var downloadContainer = angular.element(''),
      content = 'data:attachment/csv,' + encodeURI(csv);

```
  // var downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>'),
  var downloadLink = angular.element(downloadContainer.children()[0]),
      blob = new Blob([csv], {
        type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'
      });

  if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    // download file for IE
    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
  }
  else {
    downloadLink.attr('href',  content);
    downloadLink.attr('download', filename);
    downloadLink.attr('style', 'display: none');
    // workaround for Safari version that not supporting download feature.
    downloadLink.attr('target', '_blank');

    angular.element(document).find('body').append(downloadContainer);

    // need timeout here since appending DOM takes some time
    $timeout(function() {
      downloadLink[0].click();
      downloadLink.remove();
    }, 10);
  }
}
```

and call this function with

```
downloadCSV(cvs, 'myDownloadFile.csv')
```

But the downloading the file using Safari is "Unknown" file. Is there any workaround this issue.
BTW - what version of Safari does not support download feature.

Thanks

Comment: did you specify the extension on the file?

Comment: yes, called to save file with this name "myDownLoadFile.csv"
Safari version 9.x didn't support download feature so here is the workaround: downloadLink.attr('target', '_blank');